# (QML) Scroll multiple listviews

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

Is possible to scroll multiple `Listview`s together in qml??

this was my attempt:

```
        Flickable {
            id: scoreflick
            anchors.top: namesrow.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.leftMargin: units.gu(2)
            anchors.topMargin: units.gu(2)

            Row {
                spacing: namesrow.spacing

                ListView {
                            id: p1list
                            width: units.gu(9)
                            height: units.gu(20)
                            model: 30

                            delegate: TextField {
                                width: ListView.view.width
                                height: units.gu(3)
                                text: "Score"
                            }
                        }

                ListView {
                            id: p2list
                            width: units.gu(9)
                            height: units.gu(20)
                            model: 30

                            delegate: TextField {
                                width: ListView.view.width
                                height: units.gu(3)
                                text: "Score"
                            }
                        }

                ListView {
                            id: p3list
                            width: units.gu(9)
                            height: units.gu(20)
                            model: 30

                            delegate: TextField {
                                width: ListView.view.width
                                height: units.gu(3)
                                text: "Score"
                            }
                        }

                ListView {
                            id: p4list
                            width: units.gu(9)
                            height: units.gu(20)
                            model: 30

                            delegate: TextField {
                                width: ListView.view.width
                                height: units.gu(3)
                                text: "Score"
                            }
                        }

            }

        }

        Scrollbar {
            flickableItem: scoreflick
            align: Qt.AlignTrailing
        }
```

but each `Listview` scroll by itself and the `Scrollbar` does not work at all... any help?

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me. You will need somehow:

```
    onContentXChanged: {
        if(activeFocus){
            p2list.contentX = p1list.contentX  
iterate all list
for (var i=0; i<listOfListView.children.length; i++){
    if(listOfListView.children[i].activeFocus) {

    }
}
```